# What are the tradeoffs associated with the various XGBoost interfaces?

Tags: xgboost

I'm spinning up with XGBoost today, and have already encountered at least two ways to train gradient boosted trees:

### Approach 1 ("native" xgb)

*source:* [XGB python intro](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_intro.html)

```py
xg_train = xgb.DMatrix(data = X_train, label = y_train)
xg_train.save_binary('./data/processed/train.buffer')
xg_train = xgb.DMatrix('./data/processed/train.buffer')

param = {'max_depth':2, 'eta':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic'}
clf = xgb.train(param,xg_train, 100) # 1.79s wall time
```

### Approach 2 ("sklearn-style")

*source:* [XGB sklearn wrapper example](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/guide-python/sklearn_examples.py)

```py
clf2 = xgb.XGBClassifier(
    n_estimators=100, max_depth=2, eta=1, objective="binary:logistic",
    random_state=1729
)
clf2.fit(train[['distance_from_net', 'angle']], train['is_goal'].astype(int))
```

I've checked that the results (i.e. predictions on a validation set) are identical, but are there hidden tradeoffs associated with each approach? i.e:

- **speed?** Is data binarization handled behind the scenes in approach 2? I recorded the following with `timeit`:

```
Approach 1  1.11 s ± 25.2 ms per loop (7 runs)
Approach 2  1.58 s ± 367 ms per loop (7 runs)
```

- **completeness** do the interfaces in Approach 2 or 3 give up access to any features of "native" xgb?